# Do something once at maximum with a Control during a page life-cycle

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have implemented a color picker control in a web forms project and would like to make sure that CSS/JS is loaded maximum once. I have tried the following:

```
Protected Shared _clientNeeded As Boolean = True
Public Sub NeedClient()

    If (_clientNeeded) Then
        _clientNeeded = False
    Else
        Return
    End If
    'Loading the client-side
End Sub
```

The problem is that after building, `_clientNeeded` is true at first but then becomes false and will be false forever, so Shared, as my try did not fulfill my goal. So, how could I make sure that loading the client-side will occur if there are color pickers, but not more than once.

Comment: Use `Session` variable

Comment: That's user-level persistence. I would like to have a page-level persistence, but not sure how to do it in asp.net.

Comment: You can't achieve what you need using `Shared` or `Static` as this is not the safe way to do your task; you might need to implement a custom class for your needs;

Comment: Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919095/lifetime-of-asp-net-static-variable) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/295786/STATIC-variables-LifeTime-in-ASP-NET-application) and be vary of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154892/scope-of-static-variable-in-multi-user-asp-net-web-application)

Comment: I understand that Shared is not the solution. This is the starting point of the question as well. Basically this could be solved by adding a property to the Page owning the Control and having access to that property from the control. But that is hacky. So I wonder whether there is a better solution

Comment: You have the solution :) If you have `User Control` or `Custom Control`, I vote for your way; I did it in similar fashion when I had to retain a value like this

Comment: You are probably right, but I will wait for other inputs as well. If there will be answers I will choose the best one. If not, then I will answer the question.

Comment: one murky way is to define a `Class` with multiple properties - one for each page; store that object in `Session` and perform read/write in the page with the property relevant to that page

Comment: That would mean one/page life cycle. If n users are loading the same page at the same time, that would be n values for that page. The problem is that the value of Session should be emptied. I still stick to the Page property idea as the best so far, but I hope there are more elegant ways. For now I will implement that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement the property with a combination of [Context.Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020674/why-cant-i-access-page-viewstate-in-usercontrol) and ViewState. When the page loads several controls, the value of ClientNeeded can be shared between them through the `Context.Items` of the page. Once the property has been set, each control can store it in its own ViewState, so that it is maintained as long as the page is active:

```
protected bool ClientNeeded
{
    get
    {
        object value = ViewState["ClientNeeded"];

        if (value != null)
        {
            return (bool)value;
        }
        else
        {
            value = Context.Items["ClientNeeded"];
            if (value != null)
            {
                ViewState["ClientNeeded"] = value;
                return (bool)value;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    set
    {
        Context.Items["ClientNeeded"] = value;
        ViewState["ClientNeeded"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: How long will Context Items live?

Comment: Only for one request of the page. If you need the information for a longer time (as long as the page is active), it could be combined with the ViewState.

Comment: Can you elaborate that?